# How to show rendered html text in ui?

Tags: html, css, sql, sql-server

I have HTML content from sql query.When I am showing this in UI it is displaying tags too.I want to show the text with the html properties(bold).

My text : **Total Amount**

This is show as **Test** in ui.When i checked with fire fug it is showing as "><b>Test<b>

from sql :  `'<b>Total Amount</b>' AS Amount`

How can I solve this?

Comment: share your  code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be caused by using jquery text() method when you are showing your result in the UI. You have to use `$('#yourHtmlTag').html('<b>Total Amount</b>')` instead of `$('#yourHtmlTag').text('<b>Total Amount</b>')`.